# Printing a square + axes in a graph in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a code in java to print a square in a graph and also the axes of the graph. It asks the user where in the graph the square has to be, and for the length of the sides. I have written this code, and it does print the axes but not the square. Please help me find what's wrong with it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

     int xStart = 0, xEnd = 14, yStart = 14, yEnd = 0;

     Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print("Position in x:");
       int positionInX = Integer.parseInt(scnr.nextLine());

     System.out.print("Position in y:");
       int positionInY = Integer.parseInt(scnr.nextLine());

     System.out.print("Length of the square:");
       int lengthOfSquare = Integer.parseInt(scnr.nextLine());

     System.out.println("^");

       for (int y = yEnd; y <= yStart; y++){
         System.out.println("|");

         if (y == yStart){
           System.out.print("+");
         }

         for (int x = xStart; x <= xEnd && y == yStart; x++){
           System.out.print("-");

           if (y <= (lengthOfSquare + positionInY) && y >= (positionInY) && x <= (lengthOfSquare + positionInX) && x >= (positionInX)) {
             System.out.print("#");
           }
           else if (x != xStart && y != yStart) {
             System.out.print(" ");
           }

          if(x == xEnd){
             System.out.println(">");
           }

         }


       }
  }
}
```

It should look something like this (assuming position in x = 0, position in y = 0, and length = 4):

```
^                     
|                          
|                            
|                        
|                      
|                      
|                         
|                       
|                      
|                        
|                 
|                
|####               
|####                      
|####            
|####          
+--------------->
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a major problem:

```
int xStart = 0, xEnd = 15, yStart = 0, yEnd = 15;

for (int y = yEnd; y <= yStart; y++)  {
```

The loop starts with `y` equal to 15 (`yEnd`), and continues until `y` is less-than-or-equal-to `0` (`yStart`).

It will never execute.

I don't understand why you would start your loop with `yEnd` and end with `yStart`. And why `yEnd` would be statically assigned to 15. Should `yEnd` be assigned to the y-value as input by the user?

Comment: `yEnd` is on the bottom, but you need to print starting at the top. Right? `(0,0)` is `(xStart,yStart)`, and `(15,15)`, for example, is `(xEnd,yEnd)`.

Comment: Sorry. I did have that edited on my code in java. It says: int xStart = 0, xEnd = 15, yStart = 15, yEnd = 0; but it still does not work.

Comment: As far as I can see, `xEnd` and `yEnd` should both be assigned to the user-input values.

Comment: The grid has to be 15 units long; that's why it has those values assigned.

Comment: I see your output now. It's a *graph*, with a square cuddled into the bottom left. In future questions, the more information you add to your post, the better we can help you. And the more you show what you have specifically tried yourself (with stack traces and input text, etc), the less you'll get downvoted. Good luck!

Comment: It still just prints the graph. That is my problem.

Comment: This code is complicated. You're going to need to debug it, either with a debugger, or with lots of `System.out.println(NUMBERANDGOODINFO)`s. Chop it down into digestable pieces, and don't proceed until the next piece works. Or re-write it completely, now that you hopefully know somewhat better. When you get further, update your post with what you have tried, and with the specific errors you are getting, and then we can help you more. If it's a huge leap of progress, then just post a whole new question. This is really a help-others-who-help-themselves site.